# Pandas method to apply a function on the entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

I have created a function where I need to pass data frame I get shape and return me df.head()

```
    def shape_of_df(df):
        tup = df.shape
        print('Shape of df  is Rows :{0[0]},column:{0[1]}'.format(tup))
        return df.head()
```

Now when I call function with items.apply(shape_of_df) I get error however if I call function and pass df as parameter it works fine. Please let me know I am missing something very basic when I use df.apply() couldn't figure out in docs

```
   shape_of_df(items) # this works fine prints shape and df.head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the docs explains that [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) will "Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame" (i.e., along the rows or along the columns).

You want to apply a function on the entire dataFrame instead, so if you're trying to chain functions, you should look into [`DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html). The usage is similar:

```
items.pipe(shape_of_df)
```

As long as you satisfy the condition that `shape_of_df` accepts a DataFrame as input and correspondingly returns one as output.

Comment: wow thank you very much I was so dumb and clueless didn't even realize